# Manage Large APK Expansion File

Tags: android, performance, apk, apk-expansion-files

I'm using an expansion file (~500mb) that contains videos and more than 20.000 image files.

Which is the best way to manage this file?

For now, i'm loading the ZipFileResource object in my Application class when i check if this file is already downloaded.

One of the uses for this expansion file, is to provide images for a gigapixel view, but it takes a lot of time to load one image, and it should load about 30 images in 200ms. 
Before i move this image files to an expansion file, there were in assets folder and worked well.

I'm planning unzip the expansion file at the external storage and remove the obb file, but i don't know if it's a good choice.

Can you tell me some advices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you, you'll download your mediafiles after you have installed the App. For this I would make it like that, download it and save it to the SD-Card (I would do this in an AsyncTask). Now you save every path of your picture or video into your DB. If you want to get the picture read it out the db and fill your ImageView or whatever. This way is really fast.

I hope I could help you.
safari

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use Zip files as extension files once and I have found that they work very slowly.

OBB files works fast, just as with your regular file system.

> I'm planning unzip the expansion file at the external storage and remove the obb file, but i don't know if it's a good choice.

It's bad choise. [Google](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#StorageLocation) doesn't recommend:

> To ensure proper behavior, you must not delete, move, or rename the expansion files.